# Cannot perform update query because update values are not defined

Tags: graphql, typeorm

I am trying to execute a mutation like so

```
mutation creating {
  createTeam(
    payload: {
      name: "Team von abc"
      tacts:["94b4cbc2-b996-482f-b712-967bdb646e73"]
    }
  ) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

This results in :

> "message": "Cannot perform update query because update values are not
>   defined. Call \"qb.set(...)\" method to specify updated values.",

My graphql is defined like this:

```
input CreateTeamPayload {
    name: String
    tacts:[ID!]
}

type Team {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    tacts: [Tact]!
}

type Query {
    fetchTeams: [Team]!
    fetchTeamById(id: ID!): Team
}
type Mutation {
    createTeam(payload: CreateTeamPayload): Team!
}
```

My Team requires an ID from a "tact" so I provide him with an ID from a "tact" I created before. Is this approach wrong? How can I mutate types that reference other types? is there some documentation that actually does this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your `GraphQL` schema and query. The error message is related to `typeorm`. Can you update your question with the query you are doing?

Comment: One potential source for that specific `typeorm` error is missing a `cascade: true` option in relation config: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3869#issuecomment-475691210